# How to use num2date/ date2num with Tkinter mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter, tail-recursion

I have this code inside a tkinter `mainloop()`:

```
self.raw_start_date = num2date(date2num(dt.datetime.strptime(self.end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")) - self.period)
self.start_date = self.raw_start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

I get the following error:

> File "D:\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1949, in
>   **getattr**
>       return getattr(self.tk, attr) RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Can someone please help out with this?

Comment: are you inheriting from a tk widget but forgetting to call `super().__init__()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is an artifact of subclassing `tkinter.Tk` and overriding the `__init__` method without ever calling `Tk.__init__`:

```
import tkinter

class Application(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        "do out stuff, forget to call Tk.__init__(self) !"
        pass


app = Application()

app.any_possible_attribute_name #recursion error here
```

This happens because:

1. `Tk.__init__` initializes the very important `.tk` attribute.
2. Any attribute lookup (that cannot be resolved) is forwarded to the `.tk` attribute.

So normally if you did `app.thing` and `.thing` was not already defined then it would try to return `app.tk.thing`, but when `app.tk` is not defined then it tries to look up `app.tk.tk` which requires looking up `app.tk` which causes the recursion error.

---

### To fix this

Just remember to call `Tk.__init__(self)` in your initialize method:

```
import tkinter

class Application(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        "do out stuff, just make sure to call Tk.__init__(self) !"
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)


app = Application()

app.any_possible_attribute_name
#now we just get an AttributeError
```